# IntelliJ No files were downloaded for org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to connect a telegram repository, but it gives me an error"No files were downloaded for org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0"

Following are the steps I did to add spring jar files

1. `Clicked on File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Clicked on "+" Sign -> Library -> From Maven`
2. Searched for `org.telegram:telegrambots:4.4.0`
3. Downloaded to lib folder under my project.
4. Got Error.

I don't know where it went wrong. I am new to java and spring application.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to comment, but I just experienced the same thing. But I ended up trying to download the wrong file. I needed the `redux-kotlin-js` version instead of the `redux-kotlin-linarm` version.

I've come across a few tips which may or may not work in your situation.

- `File -> Invalidate cache / restart`
- In the right side of your screen is a bar with horizontal `maven` menu
- In this menu you can click `clean` & `install`
- download the jar of the library from the internet